# DAO error:-Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, data-access-object

I am new to android development and I am trying to make a notes app by following the android architecture components but on running I am getting errors in my DAO if any one could help would be highly grateful.
Here's the code and the error that I am getting.

[image: Error That I am getting]

DAO:-

'''

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(note :Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(note : Note)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes_table order by id")
    fun getALL(): LiveData<List<Note>>

    @Query("SELECT * From Notes_table where id= :pos")
    fun getSpecific(pos :Int):Note

}
```

'''

Entity:-

'''

```
@Entity(tableName = "Notes_table")
data class Note(@ColumnInfo(name="noteText") val text:String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id:Int =0

}
```

'''
Database:-

'''

```
@Database(entities = [Note::class],version = 1,exportSchema = false)
abstract class NoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getNoteDao():NoteDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: NoteDatabase?=null

        fun getDatabase(context :Context):NoteDatabase{

            return Instance ?: synchronized(this){
                val instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                NoteDatabase::class.java,"note_database").build()
                Instance=instance
                instance
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Imports For DAO:-

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.
```

Imports for Entity:-

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
```

Imports for Database:-

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
```

I can provide the rest of the code if required.

Comment: try to add return type return type in insert method 
suspend fun insert(note :Note) : Long

Comment: Plead add to code snippets imports section, maybe you accidentally import wrong class with same name but other package

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed thanks for the reply can you explain why should I add a return type to an Insert function as there is nothing to return as that function inserts a row in my entity.
Still I tried your and unfortunately it didn't worked and I received the same error

Comment: There is something wrong in your DAO. try to remove all methods from your DAO and run your app

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed I guess there was some issues with the room version that I added in my dependencies I updated it and now it's working fine thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help in the comment section and by reading the documentation I figured that something was wrong with my DAO and eventually it was something to do with the **ROOM** Version that I added to my dependencies I just updated those and now it's working fine.

Comment: _it was something to do with room version_ - it would have been better if you were clear about the details so your answer would help people with similar problems

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem today, fixed by updating `Room` version from `2.3.0` to `2.4.0-beta02`. Version can be found here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-alpha04

Answer (score 3):

It's Working for me to update the Room version: 2.4.2

```
   implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
   kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
   implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
   androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by raising room version to "2.4.0-beta01"

Answer (score 1):

## October 2023

`kapt` annotation processing tool didn't work for me with `suspend` functions.

What I did to fix it:

root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.room_version = '2.5.2'
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.2' apply false
    //kotlin gradle plugins
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.9.0-1.0.13' apply false
}
```

I noticed that *kotlin gradle plugins* version has to match *ksp plugin* version or it does not work(ksp version 1.8 didn't work for me).

app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    //id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    //DOES NOT WORK
    //kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```